# Help with structs

Tags: c

im making a simple text game in c just for fun, but is having some problems with structs and/or Visual Studio 2010. I've started a empty C++ project, but my main main file is main.c.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    struct Player
    {
        char name[256];
        int sum;
    };

    struct Player player;
    strcpy(player.name, "John");
    player.sum = 0;

    struct Player cpu;
    strcpy(cpu.name, "Bob");
    cpu.sum = 0;

    printf("\n\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the compiler is complaining alot! One of them:

Syntax error: missing ; before type (struct Player cpu line)

Rest is related to that cpu is not a struct and therefor non of the members gets recon by the compiler.

What have i done wrong with my struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, you have to declare all of your local variables first, at the beginning of the scope. You should move the `struct Player cpu;` declaration on the line right after `struct Player player;`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Didier, you can make a .cpp file instead of .c with the content you have and the compiler will run well

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is valid C++ but not valid C. Change your filename to main.cpp and it should build just fine in Visual Studio.